# Cannot set default selection on <ion-select> on Reactive form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to load `<ion-select>` dynamically in a reactive form.It is working fine.Now I need to set default selection.I have used `selected` attribute for that.But it is not working.Can you tell me why?

Here is [**the Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mm2ueT?p=preview)

*app/home.page.html*

```
<form [formGroup]="detailInformationForm" (submit)="goToSponsor(detailInformationForm)" novalidate>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Donation</ion-label>
      <ion-select formControlName="donationdate">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let date of donationDates" value="{{date.donationdate}}" [selected]="date.isChecked">
          {{date.donationdate}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
       <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!detailInformationForm.valid">Next</button>
  </form>
```

*app/home.page.ts*

```
export class HomePage {
  donationDates:any=[];
  detailInformationForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navController: NavController,public formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
      this.donationDates = [
       {
          id: null,
          donationid: "2",
          donationdate: "2017-03-12",
          datedescription: "Vad Bij",
          isChecked:true
      },
      {
        id: null,
       donationid: "2",
       donationdate: "2017-03-19",
       datedescription: "Sud satam",
       isChecked:false
     }]

     this.detailInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
      donationdate: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

**Update:**

```
 this.getDonation().then((val) => {//get Donation
      this.donation = val;
      if (this.donation.sponsordata == 1) {
        this.detailInformationForm.controls['attendees'].validator = Validators.required;
      }

      let donationDates = this.donation.donationdates;
      let dates = [];
      _.forEach(donationDates, function (value, key) {
        value.isChecked = false;
        if (key == 0) {
          value.isChecked = true;
        }
        dates.push(value);
      });
      this.donationDates = dates;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control in the reactive form will be managing the selected item.

Instead of specifying the `selected` attribute, just specify the value for 
the `donationdate` control that is to be selected:

```ts
this.donationDates = [
  {
    id: null,
    donationid: "2",
    donationdate: "2017-03-12",
    datedescription: "Vad Bij",
    isChecked: true
  },
  {
    id: null,
    donationid: "2",
    donationdate: "2017-03-19",
    datedescription: "Sud satam",
    isChecked: false
  }
]
const checked = this.donationDates.find(donationDate => donationDate.isChecked);

this.detailInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
  donationdate:
    [
      checked ? checked.donationdate : null,
      Validators.required
    ]
});
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hadn't noticed that you were using the `donationdate` property as the control value, rather than the object instance that contained it.

Comment: do I need to remove `[selected]` from html page?

Comment: Yep, it's ineffectual. Angular's `ControlValueAccessor` will manage the selection for you. You just specify the value that you want selected when creating the `FormGroup` or - later - by calling [`patchValue`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#patchValue-anchor), etc.

Comment: No, then it is not working at all. With that also having problem where it always shows control is invalid.If you update the plunker which I have shared, you too can see that.

Comment: Seems fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/okFMXmpKgHNUQeUhmQOk?p=preview). Although, I would suggest using the object itself as the `option` and  control value - rather than the `donationdate` property.

Comment: I have a problem.if you see the **Update** section above where you can see that, I'm getting data from the local storage (promise).That method also inside the `constructor`.But due to nature or promise, we cannot have data on form creation time.can you tell me how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have handled the situation well.Now it's working.I need one help from you.Can you give me a good reference article about how to handle Reactive forms well.Including the suggestion which you have given above.

Comment: [This one](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) should be helpful. And [this one](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value) discusses `setValue` and `patchValue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'll go through it :)